# Angular forms: adding text area changes the values of the other ones

Tags: html, angular, forms

I'm working with forms and trying to dynamically text areas to it. But when I click the add button it works fine but it changes all the previous values with the value of the new text area.

I have tried to extract the code but didn't made it works on stackblitz (here is my try: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tns7nv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I also have tried to remove the 
    this.changesDetector.detectChanges(); but it still does not work and I have an error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Here is my code:
.ts:

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  OnInit,
  ChangeDetectorRef
} from "@angular/core";
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators
} from "@angular/forms";

export interface BlockComment {
  id?: any;
  comment?: string;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  finalComment: string[] = [];
  formProjet1: FormGroup;
  blockComment: BlockComment[] = [
    {
      id: 0,
      comment: ""
    }
  ];

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private changesDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm() {
    this.formProjet1 = this.formBuilder.group({
      comments: new FormControl("")
    });
  }

  addTextareaComment() {
    const id = new Date().getTime().toString();
    this.blockComment.push({
      id,
      comment: "TEST" // <-- THIS VALUE
    });
    this.changesDetector.detectChanges();
  }

  private getComments(): string[] {
    this.finalComment = [];
    for (const comment of this.blockComment) {
      this.finalComment.push(comment.comment);
    }
    return this.finalComment;
  }
}
```

.html

```
<div>
<form name="formProjet1" [formGroup]="formProjet1" class="repeater">
   <button (click)="addTextareaComment()" class="btn btn-primary ">Add comm</button>
   <br>
   <div>
      <div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row" *ngFor="let block of blockComment">
               <div class="col-md-9">
                  <textarea class="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  name="comments"
                  formControlName="comments"
                  [(ngModel)]="block.comment">
                  </textarea>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have every `textarea` bound to the same `formControlName="comments"`. One form control - one value. You need [FormArray](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a) instead.

The property `blockComment` will not play well with the `FormArray`. It would be more practical to store all the data in the `FormArray` instead of spreading it among the `blockComment` and the `FormArray`.

PS you need manual call to detect changes because `this.blockComment.push` does not update the reference which is in the `blockComment`. [More details about arrays and change detection in this articcle](https://chrislo.ca/angular-2345-change-detection-on-data-bound-array-pushunshift-popshift-or-splice/).

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try!